# How to start a container in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, application-server

I am trying to run  some integration tests in continous integration with TeamCity and the goal of my test is to verify if I can deploy correctly my webapp on some local container. I need therefore to setup a TeamCity build that does the same

- Build all and package my webapp
- Start the container
- Run the tests which deploy the webapp and test the deployment status
- Stop the container

How can this be done with TeamCity?

Comment: Yes, It can be done. Are you using Maven?

Comment: I hope you understand that you will need a build agent.

Comment: Yes how can I configure the build agent correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple, if you have TeamCity set up. It sounds like you're new to TeamCity. If you don't have a server and agent set up so you're able to run [build configurations](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Configuration), you'll need to do that first.

If you do, you're ready to go. You need to be able to do all the things you want to do from the command line, or from the built-in TeamCity runners. Then, you just need to set up build configurations to do each task, and then connect them with [finish build triggers](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+Build+Triggers).

Comment: cany you explain me more in detail how to put a process which is run before and killed after a maven task?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're looking for. TeamCity won't really help you do this. In the build configuration where you've created the Maven build step, you can [create a build step](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+Build+Steps) before to start the process, then add a build step after the Maven one to stop the process. But what do you need to run at the same time as Maven?

Comment: the process I want to run before the maven step is a script which launch a program. This script must be alive until the end of the maven step. How can I kill it?

Comment: What are you doing that needs a program to run while maven is running? That's a really odd task. I suppose you could (in the first build step) launch it in a way that you get its process id, then write that id to file, then run the maven build step, then in the third build step, read the file, then kill the process. But again, I think this is ill-advised.

Comment: the fact is that the program I want to run has a very complex procedure , it's a script which calls other 4 scripts which launch 4 JVM